# Installing different theme and modules using Drupal domain module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-theming, drupal-domain-access

I am trying to use drupal Domain module and I have domain_A and domain_B right now. Domain_A is my primary domain and B is the second one that I am trying to add.

Domain B will have its own theme and some additional functionalists. Everything else is pretty much same.Also the database is same..

My question is where should I put my theme and my new modules for domain B. Is it inside sites/domain_b/themes and sites/domain_b/modules? I have the theme currently inside the domain_b folder but every time i try to build the theme in domain A, its overwriting the theme for domain_B since it cannot see it.

So is the correct way is to keep the new theme and even the new modules for domain_B inside sites/all/themes and sites/all/modules folder and use domain_theme module to choose the new theme for domain_B?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why exactly are you using the domain access module? If both sites will use the same database and the same basic functionality, you are probably better off using drupals multisite functionality.

Comment: We need to share the content between the sites and even the users too..So we think domain module would be the best way to go..

Comment: If you are sharing all users and all content, I think drupals own multisite capability would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the domain access module it is fine to add all themes to the sites/all/themes folder. What controls which theme is used is the domain_theme module, not which folder the theme is in (which would be the case in a multisite install).
When you are using the domain access module you really organize everything as if it was a single site, then left the different domain modules do the rest.